# Upload Multiple Binary to Google Play

Tags: smartface.io

Is it possible to get multiple APK binaries vary by processor architectures (ARM, X86) in Smartface App Studio? I don't know how can I achieve this situation and upload them to Google Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

About getting multiple apks(ARM and x86), you can check this link : 
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/project/publishing-procedures/

In order to upload these two apks(with ARM architecture and x86 architecture), you should get publish one by one, not two of them at the same time.

One thing you need to pay attention is that, changing the versionCode value in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
android:versionCode="1"
```

The versionCode for x86 must be higher than the one in ARM.

Open AndroidManifest, change the versionCode as it should be(if this is already an application on GooglePlay, then you should now the correct versionCode), for example let's say it is 1. 
Get publish for ARM. 
Then increment the versionCode by one, it will become 2, and get publish for x86.
At last, you will have 2 apks with different versionCodes.

The second important thing is that, firstly you should upload the apk with x86 structure. After that you can turn to advanced mode and upload the second apk with ARM structure to GooglePlay.

If device can run x86 apk, then it automatically will download the one with x86 architecture. If not, then the apk with ARM architecture will be downloaded.